# $f_n=\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n}1_{[0,n]} (x) $ and usage of Lemma of Fatou

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Given the sequence: $f_n=\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n}1_{[0,n]} (x) $

I have to show whether the following inequations are correct:

1. $\displaystyle\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \int f_n d\lambda \ge \int \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} f_n d\lambda$
2. $\displaystyle\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} \int f_n d\lambda \le \int \lim\sup_{n\to\infty} f_n d\lambda$

the non-negativity condition of the lemma is met.

So where do we have problems here? I would say both inequalities hold

Answer (score 1):

2. is false. RHS is $0$ because $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x$. But $\int f_n(x)dx=2+(-1)^{n}$ so LHS is $3$. .

Comment: so why does the Fatou Lemma does not hold for this one?

Comment: Fatou's Lemma is not about $\lim \sup$. It is not clear why you think Fatou's Lemma would give 2). @Dave

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma

Here it is called the "reverse Fatou Lemma" but in our course we had it as an extension of the Fatou Lemma if there exists such a measurable, integrable majorant function g

Comment: Integrable majorant is a serious condition and it is not satisfied here. How did you conclude that 2) must be true without checking this condition?  @Dave

Comment: i did not conclude that is it true, but i am failing to show that it is not satisfied here